# Password not accepted: "Sorry try again"

Tags: password

I know my password. Used it in the past many times.
I know whoami.
When I tried today to upgrade/update, password was not accepted: "Sorry try again".
I found sln: reboot, recovery mode, root, passwd...
Seemed to work as described.
Except, when rebooting, the password was not accepted.
Computer is Dell Studio 1555, running Ubuntu 20.04.
Any idea?

Comment: Is the password not being accepted at the login screen, or only when trying to upgrade the system? 

Comment: <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>?